# extract date hours minutes and seconds from date string fomat (2021-09-04T20:02:33,315Z) in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, awk, logfile

I have a log file and each row in a log file contains data with timestamp in the format `2021-09-04T20:02:33,315Z` and I want to filter the last 30 seconds logs alone from the log file.

I found awk can be used to extract the dates in the range

```
sudo awk -vDate=$(date -d '30 seconds ago' +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S,000Z) '{ if ($4 > Date) print Date FS $4}'
```

But I am stuck on if condition in the command to extract date hours minutes and seconds to check the condition.

Comment: do you take milliseconds into consideration when calculating the 30-sec range, eg, for the sample provided ... would `02:03,000` be displayed or must the time >= `02:03,315`? the `awk` code is looking for log entries within the last 30 seconds based on the **current** time ... so if the last entry in the log was made 3 hrs ago you want to show nothing ... is this correct? or do you want to see the last 30 seconds based on the last timestamp in the log file?

Comment: No, I am not taking milliseconds into the consideration and 30 seconds entries by only considering the current time. I don't want to consider the logger which is even before 30 seconds

Answer (score 0):

You can use range in awk with a coma (`,`) between two tests.

Like this:

```sh
awk '$1$2$3 > "Sep3008:47:46", $1$2$3 < "Sep3008:54:04" {print $0}' /var/log/messages
```

You can compute timestamp before with your format like in your example:

```sh
awk -v TS1=$(date ...) -v TS2=$(date ...) '$4 > TS1, $4 < TS2 { print ...}'
```